# Self Join and aggregate based on specific dates (redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to do a self join and get the data in the format, however, I'm getting incorrect data. I need to sum up `qty` based on `art_no`, `site`, `manufact` for each `evt_start` date. And the `evt_start` date should fall between `evt_start` and `date2`.

```
select sum(a.qty) as over_all_qty,
b.art_no,b.site,b.evt,b.evt_start,a.manufact

from wo_sup a

left join wo_sup b on a.site = b.site
and a.art_no = b.art_no
and a.manufact = b.manufact
and a.evt_start = b.evt_start

where a.evt_start between b.evt_start and b.date2

group by 

b.art_no,b.site,b.evt,b.evt_start,a.manufact
```

Comment: Aside: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Noted. thank you. @EricBrandt

Answer (score 1):

Your evt_start date (all are 2020) is less than the date2 column for all but one record.

So, either your data-set is incorrect or what you want to do is:

```
a.evt_start between b.date2 and b.evt_start
```

Thus, change either your data-set or your 'between' condition and you will get all 4 rows in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is undoing the `left join`.  Does this work in Redshift?

```
left join
wo_sup b
       on a.site = b.site and
          a.art_no = b.art_no and
          a.manufact = b.manufact and
          a.evt_start = b.evt_start and
          a.evt_start between b.evt_start and b.date2
```

Comment: I tried this, But I'm only getting one manufact data in the output. The rest are not showing up.